# How do I set up to highlight cell L2 red if date entered is greater than 7 days of date entered in K2?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am creating a tracker in Excel for response time for a business partner to act on a task after the assistant assigns them the task. If the business partner has not responded in greater than 7 days from the day they were given the assignment (K2), I would like the cell L2 to turn red. Which would indicate to the assistant that she needs to harp on the business partner to get their job done.

To sum up, if K2 = 02/07/14 then the business partner must respond by 02/14/14, but if they do not, then the cell must be red. It would be something like "If today's date is > K2 + 7 days, then highlight cell red." This is if there is a date entered into K2 (mm/dd/yy).

Additionally, I would want the cell to highlight green if the date entered in L2 is within 7 days of the date entered in K2. So that if/then statement would read, "If date entered in L2 is < or = K2, then highlight cell green."

Comment: Are you using MS Excel?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what you want but please try:

```
 =AND(L1<>"",K1-L1>7)  
 =AND(K1<>"",K1+7<TODAY())
```

It may do the opposite of what you want, but that should be easy to fix it you have some data for testing.

In Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., Use a formula to determine which cells to format and Format values where this formula is true: with green for the first formula above and red for the last. May be applied to the whole of ColumnL.